# Allowed Values list in drupal CCK Fields

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, loops, cck

I'm basically looking to simply print out each of the allowed values in a CCK field..

i know the allowed values are stored inside a text field within the table: 'content_node_field'.

the values are then stored within 'global_settings'

I'm looking to somehow print out each individual allowed value using a PHP loop.

however with all values being stored within one text field.. im finding it hard to print out each value individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
// Get the global_settings like you described.
$serialized_data = db_result(db_query("..."));
// Unserialize the data.
$unserialized_data = unserialize($serialized_data)
// Foreach the allowed values.
$values = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $unserialized_data['allowed_values']) as $value) {
  $values[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: sorry, having a few problems with the foreach loop.

getting this error: warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\sites\all\modules\custom\marli\marli.admin.inc on line 11.

where it says 'allowed_values' ive put the field 'global_settings' (which containts the data.

Comment: Sorry to be a complete pain.. how would i be able to store each individual value into a variable? for example:
$value = array();
$a = $value['a'];
$b = $value['b'];

i feel like im close to what im trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right, you can create PHP arrays by simply suffixing the `[]` to the names of the fields, so for example:

```
<input type="text" name="myname[]" />
```

Now you can get the values of the array like this:

```
foreach($myname as $value)
{
  echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

**Update Based On Comment:**

You can use the **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** function to convert your data to array and then manipulate accordingly:

**Example:**

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: Within the field global_settings contains the multiple values.. example:

a:4:{s:15:"text_processing";s:1:"0";s:10:"max_length";s:0:"";s:14:"allowed_values";s:17:"A*
A
B
C
D
E";s:18:"allowed_values_php";s:0:"";}

im looking to output each grade (a, b, c, d, e) and strip the rest away now i know there is str_replace for this however im doing this on multiple fields where the contents do vary.